# Is there a Library for Song detection like Shazzam and Soundhood?

Tags: c#, java, c++, c

does somebody know a library (language does not care) for song recognition like the Services provided by Shazzam and Soundhood?

Best Regards,
Christian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. http://echonest.com offer an online API for this. IIRC they're working in collaboration with http://musicbrainz.org (a huge, open music database) to gather acoustic fingerprints on the musicbrainz catalogue. Both have a comprehensive selection of open source tools on github related to this activity. You can download your own fingerprinting server (and, once again IIRC) [get all the fingerprints too](http://echoprint.me/data_download).

https://github.com/metabrainz/

https://github.com/echonest/

Comment: http://blog.musicbrainz.org/?p=945

Answer (score 1):

This is a large and complex project that will require you to have a lot of knowledge in different areas. See [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint) for more information.